# Intercept bash script functions/system calls and wrap them into custom function

Tags: python, linux, bash, shell, profiling

Having a bunch of bash scripts, from which `python`, `bash`, `sqlplus`, `php` scripts are triggered is it possible to create some kind of bash wrapper that will intercept each call and modify it, e.g. given `some_script.sh` with following code

```
#! /bin/bash
source $SOME_ENV/activate
python some_script.py
```

I want instead of calling `$: python some_script.py` call `$: time python some_script.py`
So what I want to do is intercept calls to `python, php, sqlplus` or whatever
and insert `time` command in every call, than gather timings and save it to somewhere, knowing to which script this timing are related.

Is it possible?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If `activate` is supposed to enable this feature, it could be filled with functions such as:

```
python() {
  echo python "$@" >>timelog.txt
  { time command python "$@" } 2>>timelog.txt; }
}
```

This won't work exactly like the `time` builtin normally works. In particular, it will not time pipelines; it will only time the `python` call itself. Also, any output to stderr from the script will be redirected to the logfile.

Comment: Consider `printf "python"; printf " %q" "$@"; printf "\n"` instead of the `echo`.  It will properly quote all arguments.